# React: create dismissable Alert component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a React component that will use bootstrap `alert` classes to display errors. The problem is that I want to make it dismissable, but attaching a handler in the close button inside the alert div to hide it will not make it re-render if I need to display the error again. Example:

```
class Alert extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      display: true
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      display: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.display && 
          <div className={"alert alert-" + this.props.type + " alert-dismissible mt10"}>
            {this.props.message}
            <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.handleClick} data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is a working code for the Alert component, and clicking in the close button inside it will hide it. Here's the issue:

```
class FormImageUpload extends React.Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Paste Image Url"/>
        {this.props.displayUploadError && 
          <Alert type="danger" message="There was an error trying to process the image. Please try again." />
        }
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt10">SEND</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

root parent:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      displayUploadError: false
    }
    this.handleRequest = this.handleRequest.bind(this)
  }


  handleRequest(image_url) {
      this.setState({
        displayUploadError: true
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo__wrap">
        <FormImageUpload 
          handleRequest={this.handleRequest}
          displayUploadError={this.state.displayUploadError}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have a boolean that indicates if I need to show/hide the Alert component. But if I closed the alert, it'll not be displayed again. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than setting the state of the alert,  set the state in the form and pass the state as props. It should work then. 
And onclick of the alert update the state of the form upload component,  using a callback function.

Comment: But the point is to create a reusable component that can hide itself. I already have a boolean in the form component for displaying/hiding the Alert

Comment: Why do you need two flags 2 hide it,  simply pass the boolean from form to alert as prop

Comment: Your alert is not re rendering because you set the state of the alert component but the form component does not get to know about the change. Hence change the state of the form and pass it down to the children

Comment: It should be dismissable, I use the first boolean to first know if I need to render the Alert and the other one is for the Alert component to be able to hide itself. But when it hide itself I can't display it again

Comment: Try it out with the same boolean by passing it as props

Comment: and how do I hide the alert in the button click handler?

Comment: Using callback functions.

Comment: Update the state of form and that will re render the child components

Comment: But then I'll need to create the function to hide the Alert in the parent component and pass down the function to the Alert component. I want to know if it's possible to make the alert hide itself from the Alert component by only passing one bolean property from the parent

Comment: the boolean on the form isn't state, it comes from it's parent component

Answer (score 0):

Yes passing a boolean can also hide it. 
Here is a mock code

```
    If (boolean) {
 Return Alert
} 
Else {
Return null
}
```

Comment: Use it like this in alert

Comment: I've added my root parent component to the question. How can I make this work when hiding the alert from a click handler inside the Alert component but making it be displayed again when the root parent state updates?